# discord.js \n doesn't break line in embed description

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const channel = options.getChannel("channel");
const title = options.getString("title");
const msg = options.getString("description");

const ancEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('DARK_VIVID_PINK')
  .setTitle(title)
  .setDescription(msg)
       
channel.send({embeds: [ancEmbed]});
```

What might be wrong with this?
`\n` don't get replaced into new lines..
[image: Discord Embed Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're setting the description to the content of the user's command, and if the user inputs a `\n`, Discord automatically escapes it so that your interaction receives it as the *text* \n, not the *newline* \n. Here's a replace function using a regex that replaces all the *text* `\n` with an actual *newline* `\n` character of the content of the message:

```js
var msg = options.getString("description");
msg = msg.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
```